Natural method book for Dutch?
Does anyone know of a book for learning Dutch by the natural method or something like it please?
I'm thinking of something like Lingua Latina Per Se Illustrata or Erstes Deutches Buch.

Hi and welcome to Language Learning Stack Exchange. Could you please be more specific about what you expect from that book? The direct method or natural method is an approach to language teaching in a classroom rather than something you can get from a book. A book alone (even when accompanied by audio resources) cannot teach a language using the direct method.

Thank you.
Well-known examples of books which use the natural method include Lingua Latina Per Se Illustrata and Erstes Deutches Buch. There are a number of others, but I haven't found one for Dutch.

In the Netherlands and Flanders, languages are usually taught in the target language. For this reason, course books are also in the target language. One such series of books is Zo gezegd (published by Pelckmans in Flanders), of which the first volume is Zo gezegd 1.1 Breakthrough Leerwerkboek (editie 2024). Unfortunately, the available information does not define the approach. However, the series is clearly intended for use in classrooms and is task-oriented; it has many exercises in which language learners practise things in pairs.
The series Contact! bij Intertaal (first volume: Contact! nieuw 1 tekstboek) is also designed for classroom use. It has books for the CEFR levels A1, A2 and B1.
Another series published by Intertaal is Begin vandaag (first volume: Begin vandaag 1 tekst-/werkboek+Intertaal augmented). However, this series is not based on the natural method; it is explicitly based on TPR.
Other series are KlasNL (first volume: KlasNL - Nederlands leren naar A1 - cursusboek), Start.nl (first volume: Start.nl - deel 1) and *Taaltalent (Taaltalent deel 1), all published by Coutinho in the Netherlands. There aren't many details about the method but all of them are designed for classroom use.
